# What is the name of the move that Obi-wan uses to remove Anakin's limbs?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

I could be thinking of something else in the Star Wars universe but is the move that Obi-Wan used to remove the limbs of Anakin called something? Like does that move have a name? Or is there a name for any strike that removes a limb that the Jedi use?

Comment: The e-limb-minater

Comment: Let me note that in the Darths & Droids universe, Anakin got his limbs removed because he tried and failed a very dangerous move from a losing position, and that move is canonically called the "double forward Force Somersault with Force Jump and Vorpal Slice" in http://www.darthsanddroids.net/episodes/0628.html .

Comment: 'Tis but a scratch.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The severing of *several limbs at once* is referred to in the [Star Wars: The Jedi Path - A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book)) as **Mou Kei**, a variant of *Cho mai* (the severing of an arm) and *Cho mok* (the severing of a leg/other limbs)

Note the droll footnote by Obi-Wan.

[image]

And on the old [Star Wars: Galaxies](http://web.archive.org/web/20111122185449/http://starwarsgalaxies.station.sony.com/en_US/players/content.vm?id=66843&resource=features) website

> **Mou Kei
>
>   Level 66**
>
> *This maneuver is an advanced strike used to defeat a dangerous
>   opponent. With a circular motion of the Lightsaber, this attack is
>   aimed at major limbs or used to dismember opponents.*

Comment: Because *of course* they had to invent a term for it.

Comment: @Adamant - Not only do they have a term for it, the term has its own four-volume EU novel.

Comment: @Adamant *"I don't know what's scarier, dismembering someone or the fact that it happens so often that you people have a term for it."*

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach [Broken Arrow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115759/quotes?item=qt0352487)?

Comment: To be fair, we have a term for "nuclear apocalypse" (which has never happened to the best of my memory) among many other scary things